# Se hace hover a una imagen con degradado y se desbordan algunas imágenes

Tags: html5, css3, animación

Tengo un problema, resulta que al dar click en dos imágenes de la galería, se desbordan las fotos, digamos cuando están en :active, para el resto de las imágenes no aplica, se ven bien al hacer :hover y :active etc. Me parece raro porque es el mismo código para todas las fotos, por qué para unas sí sirve y para otras no??

En total son como 25 fotos, las imágenes que presentan el problema es la de la hoja de una planta que parece pintada  y la de la hoja del libro, de hecho están muy cerca ambas. Justo al darle click a esas fotos es donde se puede ver que se desbordan

[Fotos desbordadas, da click en el enlace](http://factus.mx/business_template_2/gallery-masonry.html)

```css
.gal {
  
    -ms-column-count: 3; 
    -webkit-column-count: 3; 
     -moz-column-count: 3; 
         column-count: 3;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 3px;
          
  } 

.box-img{
  
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}


.gal .box-img:not(:first-child){
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1rem;

}



.box-img img{

  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}


.box-img:hover img{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}




.box-img img:after{
  overflow: hidden;
}




.gal .box-img a:after{ 
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 350px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gal a:hover:after{
  opacity: 1;

}





@media (max-width: 500px) {
    
    .gal {  
  -ms-column-count: 1; 
  -webkit-column-count: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ /* Firefox */
    -moz-column-count: 1;
       column-count: 1;
    
  
  }
    
  }
```

```html
  <div class="gal">
  <!-- individual img -->    
   <div class="box-img">    
    <a href="img/gallery/masonry/1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">        
        <img src="img/gallery/masonry/1.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="auto">
    </a>
   </div> 
  <!-- /individual img -->
   </div>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no se porque pasa esto a base de prueba y error lo solucione.

**Comprobación**
Para comprobarlo utilice la DevTools de chrome poniendo en la etiqueta `<a>` dentro del `box-img` y le puse las propiedasdes `hover, visited, focus` y luego le añadí al `box-img` la propiedad `hover` de esa manera se puede ver claramente si falla o no falla.

**Solución**
Añadir a la etiqueta `<a>` dentro de `box-img` la propiedad `outline:none` esto quitará el `outline` que parece dar problemas

Aunque no deberia de haber problemas, el `outline` por defecto se pone cuando un elemento esta `focus` (cosa que las etiquetas se pueden hacer `focus` y los `div` les tienes que poner un atributo para que actuen así).

Esta propiedad por lo visto estaba haciendo que la animación del `scale(1.1)` funcionase mal **(ya que si cambias la propiedad `transition` en vez de `all` lo pones otra propiedad no pasa este problema)**.
Puedo hacer un montón de conjeturas sin fundamento como: "el outline ocupa 1px en cada lado" o algo así. Pero realmente no se exactamente porque existe este problema

Comment: woooow!! muchas gracias, te daría mill puntos pero la plataforma no me lo permite, mil gracias :D ya me estaba volviendo loca!!